# Can't find attribute of type `MyData` in serialized file even though it requires `MyData`

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I'm struggling with fixing a serialized pickle file right now in py2 (can't use py3).

I have a file called data.pickle that I'm trying to load with:

```
import cPickle as CP

with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as file:
  data = CP.load(file)
```

This gives the error `ImportError: No module named _my_data`

Note that `_my_data.py` is a file that I have removed. So I did `touch _my_data.py` and then this resulted in the error

```
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    data = CP.load(file)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MyData'
```

So inside `_my_data.py`, I then defined

```
class MyData:
  pass
```

Then this loaded fine. This serialized file stores an instance of `MyClass`. I then used

```
def print_nested_types(data, depth=0):
    if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
        for item in data:
            print("  " * depth + "List or Tuple: %s" % type(item))
            print_nested_types(item, depth + 1)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.iteritems():
            print("  " * depth + "Dictionary Key: %s, Type: %s" % (key, type(value)))
            print_nested_types(value, depth + 1)
    elif isinstance(data, (set, frozenset)):
        for item in data:
            print("  " * depth + "Set or FrozenSet: %s" % type(item))
            print_nested_types(item, depth + 1)
    elif hasattr(data, "__dict__"):
        for key, value in data.__dict__.iteritems():
            print("  " * depth + "Class Attribute: %s, Type: %s" % (key, type(value)))
            print_nested_types(value, depth + 1)
    elif isinstance(data, (int, float, str, bool, type(None))):
        pass  # Handle basic data types if needed
    else:
        print("  " * depth + "Other Type: %s" % type(data))

print_nested_types(data)
```

to print out all the nested attributes, but none of them printed out the `MyData`, so I'm confused where this is even used. I'm trying to remove this dependence on `_my_data`, but I don't know where it's even used. Can someone advise what to do here

Note that my ultimate goal is to just get rid of this dependency. If I don't need to find out what nested attribute has this dependency to solve this issue, then that's fine.

Comment: I think i solved the problem. For some reason the instance of `MyData` has type `Type: <type 'instance'>`. i have no idea why